# Rails Capybara Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I am trying to get tests working after switching from Webrat to Capybara.  When I try to sign in to the application I am getting a "Invalid username/password" error, despite just having created the user in a Factory using factory_girl.  The way I understand it, the user should persist for the entirety of the fixture, right?

factories.rb:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.firstname             "Test"
  user.lastname              "Test" 
  user.email                 "test@test.com"
  user.password              "testtest"
  user.password_confirmation "testtest"
end
```

layout_links.spec.rb:

```
describe "LayoutLinks" do
    before(:each) do
        wrong_user = Factory(:user)
        integration_sign_in(wrong_user)
    end

    it "should have a dashboard page" do
        get '/dashboard'
        page.should have_css('h1', :text => "Navigation#dashboard")

    end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
def integration_sign_in(user)
            visit signin_path
            fill_in :email,    :with => user.email
            fill_in :password, :with => user.password
            click_button "Sign in"
            puts page.body
        end
```

Also in spec_helper.rb is the following:

config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

```
    config.before(:suite) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
```

Shouldn't the user persist and then be successful in the `integration_sign_in` function?  I can still sign in correctly through the browser in the development environment, which has a user and the sign in was working correctly with webrat before the migration, so I am not sure what to think.  Thanks!

UPDATE:  It looks like the session isn't going to the server correctly.  On the server, when I check the value of email and password in the session, the values are incorrect:

```
puts "Post Email: " + params[:session][:email]
puts "Post Password: " + params[:session][:password]
```

the email variable has the password variable, and the password variable has no value.  Why would this be?  The client integration test maps the fields correctly:

```
fill_in :email,    :with => user.email
fill_in :password, :with => user.password
```

How can I test this further?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this worked for me

```
fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
fill_in "Password", :with => user.password
```

whereas using the  symbols failed

Comment: of interest to Rails Tutorial 1e followers trying to drop webrat

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the session wasn't going to the server correctly.  I am not sure how to account for this.

Comment: I just recreated your problem on my end when I used symbols in "fill_in" instead of strings...  however, for me the strings still don't work either.  how did you fix it?

Comment: actually the strings work fine... me confusing my test and dev dbs